# How to position two divs with content in the middle

Tags: html, css, positioning, graphical-logo

I have a project for my final that needs to be in responsive design. We haven't covered much on the subject and no javascript has been taught to us yet. I kind of get the concept but I am facing a challenge in the design of the page.

The Logo should be after the main nav, but also alongside with the search bar. However the search bar should be always in the middle of the logo's height no matter what logo it is and how wide or tall it is, and the widths of the two are roughly 63% logo and 31% search bar + submitt btn.  I cannot use a table, since for mobile devices the search bar has to fall under the logo.

I am sorry if the question is dump, at least I made sure it hasn't been asked before B)

Thank you for your time!

[image: page layout]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could do this but to start with you could use Vertial align. This is a PITA in CSS I've always found.

**Vertial Align:**

You can set your main container to `display: table-cell;` and then use `vertial-align: middle;` on your search div. This is unsupported in older versions of IE but as you're going responsive you'll have some hoops to jump through for them anyway.

```
.menuBar {
    display: table;
}

.logo, .search {
    display: table-cell;
    vertial-align: middle;
}

<div class="menuBar">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div class="search">SEARCH</div>
</div>
```

**Line Height:**

```
  #ex6     { height: 5em; line-height: 5em; }
  #ex6 *   { vertical-align: middle; }

  <div id='ex6'>
    <div class='lfloat'>lfloat</div>
    <div class='rfloat'>rfloat</div>
    <input type='checkbox'>
    <input type='text'>
    <span class='small'>small</span>
    <img src='avatar.gif'>
    normal
    <span class='large'>large</span>
  </div>
```

The line height example and others can be found here - http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/3/20/css_vertical_align/

Comment: It has to be imported into a CMS system as well and the height will be unknown, so the first one is great man, thanks a lot! B)

Just applied the css with the design and it is all cool!!!

Good luck with your work!